# Is Postgres ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING performant on tables without auto-incrementing IDs?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12, postgresql-13

I'm aware that failed upserts will cause an increment in auto-incrementing fields, but are there any other considerations to keep in mind when using `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` when inserting millions of rows continuously?

Will it cause any other type of bloat on the tables if they are lacking any auto-incrementing field?

Is it considered a non-performant technique for large bulk upserts/inserts?

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` will not cause any kind of bloat. This is a good method to load data.

All that is independent of the existence of an auto-incremented primary key, but of course you need a primary key or unique constraint, otherwise you would never get a conflict.